# Como mudar a cor do texto ?

Tags: javascript, html

```
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>Efeito digitar em página web</title>


      <script type="text/javascript">


       var posicao = 0;
       var mensagem = "Sua mensagem aqui                      ";  //Esse texto

         function rola() {
         document.getElementById("lugar").innerHTML = 
           mensagem.substring(posicao,mensagem,length);
             posicao++;
           if (posicao == mensagem.length) {
                posicao = 0;
               }
           setTimeout("rola()", 130); 
      }


    </script>
     </head>

    <body onload="rola()">
   <div id="lugar"></div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adicionei um color na div.
Veja se resolve.

```js
       var posicao = 0;
       var mensagem = "Sua mensagem aqui                      ";  //Esse texto

         function rola() {
         document.getElementById("lugar").innerHTML = 
           mensagem.substring(posicao,mensagem,length);
             posicao++;
           if (posicao == mensagem.length) {
                posicao = 0;
               }
           setTimeout("rola()", 130); 
      }
```

```css
#lugar{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
    <body onload="rola()">
   <div id="lugar"></div>
```

Comment: Resolveu amigo, obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Você pode alterar diretamente na tag:

```
 <div id="lugar" style="color:rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);">
```

Ou pelo Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("lugar").style.color =rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8);
```

Você pode criar cores randomicas basta criar uma string rgba(ou rgb) e passar para o atributo style.color, código do rgba randomico tirado [dessa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23095637/how-do-you-do-a-random-rbg-in-javascript) segue o código:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Efeito digitar em página web</title>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    var posicao = 0;
    var mensagem = "Sua mensagem aqui                      "; //Esse texto

    function rola() {
      document.getElementById("lugar").innerHTML =
        mensagem.substring(posicao, mensagem, length);
      posicao++;
      document.getElementById("lugar").style.color = random_rgba();
      if (posicao == mensagem.length) {
        posicao = 0;
      }
      setTimeout("rola()", 130);
    }

    function random_rgba() {
      var o = Math.round,
        r = Math.random,
        s = 255;
      return 'rgba(' + o(r() * s) + ',' + o(r() * s) + ',' + o(r() * s) + ',' + r().toFixed(1) + ')';
    };
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="rola()">
  <div id="lugar"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

ou apenas uma cor a cada chamada `rola()`:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Efeito digitar em página web</title>


  <script type="text/javascript">
    var posicao = 0;
    var mensagem = "Sua mensagem aqui                      "; //Esse texto



    function rola() {
      document.getElementById("lugar").innerHTML =
        mensagem.substring(posicao, mensagem, length);
      posicao++;
      if (posicao == mensagem.length) {
        posicao = 0;
      }
      setTimeout("rola()", 130);
    }

    function random_rgba() {
      var o = Math.round,
        r = Math.random,
        s = 255;
      return 'rgba(' + o(r() * s) + ',' + o(r() * s) + ',' + o(r() * s) + ',' + r().toFixed(1) + ')';
    };

    function RandomTextColor() {
      document.getElementById("lugar").style.color = random_rgba();
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body onload="rola(); RandomTextColor()">
  <div id="lugar"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

`

Comment: Boa, gostei, mas gostaria de uma cor só

Comment: @Emano80 PRONTO, atualizado

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti não seria menos custoso nessa situação adicionar diretamente na div sem função ou algo do tipo ?

Comment: O custo da função de  cor aleatória é tão pequeno , quase que nulo não muda muito, só quis dar uma versatilidade.

Comment: Arrumei a resposta, agora tem mais opções.